# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: (parent) is not associated to (child)!

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am building an application using sequelize. I currently have 3 tables; a User, a Tour, and a Location. The Location has a n:1 relationship with the Tour. The Tour has a n:1 relationship with the user.

Without the User association, the other two tables work fine. Once I add in the user association (and I have tried to do so through a migration AND by dropping and then recreating my entire database), I get a SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Location is not associated with Tour!

Here are my models:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Location = sequelize.define("Location", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [500]
      }
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Location.associate = function(models) {
    Location.belongsTo(models.Tour, {
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
  };

  return Location;
};
```

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Tour = sequelize.define("Tour", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
        },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 1000]
      }
    },
    neighborhood: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    URL: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 1000]
      }
    },
    numberOfStops: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    duration: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    tags: DataTypes.STRING
  });

    Tour.associate = function(models) {
    Tour.hasMany(models.Location);
  };

  Tour.associate = function(models) {
    Tour.belongsTo(models.User);
  };

  return Tour;
};
```

```js
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
  User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  };

  User.hook("beforeCreate", function(user) {
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(
      user.password,
      bcrypt.genSaltSync(10),
      null
    );
  });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Tour);
  };

  return User;
};
```

And here is the include statement where it is failing, and where we establish the link with the tourId to the location:

```js
app.get("/tour/:id", function(req, res) {
    db.Tour.findOne({
      where: { id: req.params.id },
      include: [db.Location]
    }).then(function(tour) {
      res.render("tour", {
        tour: tour
      });
    });
  });
```

```js
var API = {
  saveTour: function(tour) {
    return $.ajax({
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      type: "POST",
      url: "api/tours",
      data: JSON.stringify(tour)
    });
  },
  saveLocations: function(locations) {
    return $.ajax({
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      type: "POST",
      url: "api/locations",
      data: JSON.stringify(locations)
    });
  },
  getUserId: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "api/user_data"
    });
  }
};
```

```js
var tour = {
    Users: thisUser.getUserId(),
    title: title,
    description: description,
    neighborhood: neighborhood,
    URL: URL,
    duration: duration,
    tags: tags
  };

  // console.log(tour);

  if (!errors.length) {
    // Post our tour to the Tours table, then reveal the form and set our local tour object.
    API.saveTour(tour).then(function(tour) {
      document.getElementById("submit-tour").remove();
      document.getElementById("tourstopssection").style.display = "block";
      thisTour.setId(tour.id);
    });
  }
}

// Function takes in the newly created tour object, grabs DOM values for each.
function addTourLocations(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Grab and process all of our tour stops.
  var locationElements = document.getElementsByClassName("tourstop");
  var areStopErrors = false;
  var locations = [];

  // Loop over every location element on the DOM.
  for (var j = 0; j < locationElements.length; j++) {
    var children = locationElements[j].children;

    // Initialize this location with the tour id; we'll pass in data...
    var thisLocation = {
      TourId: thisTour.getId()
    };

    // ... by looping over the DOM children and grabbing their form values.
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (
        children[k].classList.value.includes("stoptitle") &&
        children[k].value
      ) {
        var stopTitle = children[k].value;
        thisLocation.title = stopTitle;
      }

      if (
        children[k].classList.value.includes("stopaddress") &&
        children[k].value
      ) {
        var stopAddress = children[k].value;
        thisLocation.address = stopAddress;
      }

      if (
        children[k].classList.value.includes("stopdescription") &&
        children[k].value
      ) {
        var stopDescription = children[k].value;
        thisLocation.description = stopDescription;
      }
    }

    // Push this location into our locations array.
    locations.push(thisLocation);
```

Finally, this is how the app/db are synced:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
var helpers = require("./lib/helpers");

var db = require("./models");
var passport = require("./config/passport");

var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

var hbs = exphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: "main",
  helpers: helpers // Require our custom Handlebars helpers.
});

//Sessions are used to keep track of our user's login status
app.use(
  session({ secret: "keyboard cat", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // Set a local variable for our user.
  next();
});

// Handlebars
app.engine("handlebars", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Routes
require("./routes/apiRoutes")(app);
require("./routes/htmlRoutes")(app);

var syncOptions = { force: false };

// If running a test, set syncOptions.force to true
// clearing the `testdb`
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  syncOptions.force = true;
}

// Starting the server, syncing our models ------------------------------------/
db.sequelize.sync(syncOptions).then(function() {
  app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log(
      "==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.",
      PORT,
      PORT
    );
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I've been googling for four days....help!

Comment: On which line is the exception occurring, what is the message? Your fourth code block seems to be pasted together from at least two locations. What is the second half supposed to be, how does it fit together with the app.get definition?

Comment: Just a guess for now, you may need to define the reverse relationship from Tour to Location as well, that a Tour has multiple Locations. "hasMany", just like you have done it for User and Tour.

Comment: @Christoph - thanks for that! I actually did establish the hasMany in the Tour model, but I had left that out in my copy/paste job last night. I updated the model and added some clarity to that last block - basically the first one (the get route) is where the error is thrown, right on the "Include: db.Location" line. The second portion is how we determine the API routing, and the third is how we are actually building the Location and Tours based on the client-side input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your associations, also why are you defining twice the association function on Tour?

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Location = sequelize.define("Location", {
    //
  });

  Location.associate = function(models) {
    Location.belongsTo(models.Tour, { as:'Tour', foreignKey:'tourId', onDelete: "cascade"});
  };

  return Location;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Tour = sequelize.define("Tour", {
    //
  });

  Tour.associate = function(models) {
    Tour.hasMany(models.Location, { as: 'Locations', foreignKey: 'tourId'});
    Tour.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'userId' });
  };


  return Tour;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    //
  });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Tour, {as: 'Tours', foreignKey: 'userId'});
  };

  return User;
};
```

And add the same on the query.

```
db.Tour.findOne({
  where: { id: req.params.id },
  include: [{ 
    model: db.Location,
    as: 'Locations'
  }]
}).then(function(tour) {
  res.render("tour", {
    tour: tour
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks very much! To answer your question, I am doing that because I am still very much new to this and It didn't even occur to me that I could combine those two statements...but it is so obvious now! I did notice though that the foreign key and 'as' are assigned automatically by sequelize. Does calling it explicitly in the model make a difference in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - the fact that I had defined the association on the tours model twice was breaking everything. Once I combined them as mentioned above, everything worked perfectly!

One other thing to note - sequelize automatically assigns the foreign key and the alias, so I left that part out.

Comment: So it looks like ellebkey figured out the solution, the double association. Then please mark her answer as the correct answer, as is custom here on Stack Overflow.